# How to make a restriction that allows me to have at most two times the same value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's imagine the staff assignment to work table:

```
id_staff | work
001        clean
001        cook
002        clean
```

How can I make it possible to only put the staff twice maximum and different work. Only with DDL.
That at the time of inserting staff 001 again (for the third time) it will not let me.
I have been researching and can the UNIQUE be used, if so, how can I make that UNIQUE be a maximum of two times?

I'm new in databases

Comment: afaik you can't do that, the better approach would be to check the data before inserting; you could also use a trigger.

Comment: OK OK men, i searching more information about this, and UNIQUE and DDL is not helpful here. Thanks men.

Comment: Constraint can check the values within current row only, not out of it (another rows, another tables - impossible). So either 2 tables (too complex) or trigger.

Comment: @PetersonMcPersson If you add a third column (maybe named "occurrence") then this is entirely possible with DDL.

Comment: It feels like a trigger is the way to go.